# compare 2 arrays in php and update the existing array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have one dynamic array  $fullplan having details sno, name, qty1,qty2;
another array(dynamic array) named $centerD having details sno, name,qty2;

I want to compare sno, name in both the arrays and update $fullplan qty2 value with corrosponding qty2 from array $centerD.

Comment: And your programming question is?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, Compare both array using foreach and update $fullplan array.

```
foreach($fullplan as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($centerD  as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        if($value['sno'] == $value1['sno'] && $value['name'] == $value1['name'])
        {
            $fullplan[$key]['qty2'] =  $value1['qty2'];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fullplan);
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering below is your array.

```
  $fullplan = array(
        'sno' => '1',
        'name' => 'jack',
        'qty1' => '20');
```

you can access the sno and name key by `$fullplan['sno]` , `$fullplan['name]`.
So its easy to compare like this `if($fullplan['sno'] == $centerD['sno'] && $fullplan['name'] == $centerD['name']){ $fullplan['qty2'] = $centerD['qty2']` }

then you can assign the new value like `$fullplan['qty2'] = "your value"`